# Converge series such that permuting the termes will change the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that for a series that converge, if we permute the element of the sum, the series doesn't necessarily converge. For exemple $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ converge but if we first sum positif termes and then negative termes, the series will not converge, i.e. $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x\frac{1}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)_{n\geq 1}$$ will not converge. I would like to have an example of a convergente series such that by permuting the termes it will still converge but to an other limit. Do you have such an example ?

Comment: As long as you take the limit of $n$ to infinity AFTER performing both sums and evaluating their difference, the result is perfectly convergent and identical to that of the first sum.

Answer (score 4):

Every convergent serie that is not absolutely convergent can converge to any value when you permute the terms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: The Riemann Series Theorem is based on the assumption that all the infinite terms of the series are available for reshuffling. But that is not a proper way to look at an infinite series. As has many argued many times at this forum, an infinite sum must be interpreted as the limit of $L$ to infinity of the $L's$ partial sum. Viewed this way, one can rearrange terms at liberty, without affecting the (convergent !) sum.

Answer (score 0):

Such series are called conditionally convergent.

Another example is:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: This series diverges.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I mistyped it, sorry.